# Ubuntu 18.04, searching in man page, how to tell which match my cursor is currently on?

Tags: command-line, bash, search

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04. In a Bash terminal, I type:

```
man apt
/upgrade
```

Then this is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Here I can type `n` or `N` to move around these matches. However, I don't know which match my cursor is currently on. How can I tell that?

BTW, I'm using MobaXterm on Win 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current match is the line at the top of the screen. This holds also when you scroll through the page (for instance with `k`, `j`, `u`, `d`, etc., or the mouse wheel). That is, when you press `n`, you jump to the next line containing the pattern below the line you are currently on (the one on the top, its line number is shown at the bottom).